# Git: How to check if the local and remote branches point to the same commit (i.e. in sync)?

Tags: git

How could I check if `feature_branch` and `origin/feature_branch` point to the same commit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can compare the output of `git-rev-parse`, such as in this bit of shell script:

```
export BRANCH_A=feature_branch
export BRANCH_B=origin/feature_branch

if [ x"$(git rev-parse $BRANCH_A)" = x"$(git rev-parse $BRANCH_B)" ]
then
    echo $BRANCH_A and $BRANCH_B are the same
fi
```

If you're not interested in using this in a script, but just want some indication of where `feature_branch` and `origin/feature_branch` are relative to each other, then the top of the output of `git status` will tell you their relative positions if they are not the same, e.g.:

```
$ git status
# On branch foo
# Your branch is behind 'origin/foo' by 187 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

However, note that this only works if your git config indicates that `origin/feature_branch` is "upstream" for `feature_branch`.  If you've created the local branch from a pre-existing remote-tracking branch, this will typically be the case.  If, instead, `feature_branch` was a new branch you created locally, you can set up that association in your config by pushing the branch with `-u`, e.g. `git push -u origin feature_branch`.)

Comment: Why you use `x` prefix?

Comment: It's an old habit, from trying to write autoconf tests that are as portable as possible. Some old shells (or implementations of `[` I guess?) could fail if the interpolated command result was the empty string or they could be interpreted as an option). For example, here's a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265847

Answer (score 7):

`git rev-parse origin/foo_branch` will not get you the latest commit hash on the remote branch. It will give you the latest commit hash that your local git repository knows about on the remote branch.

If you want to compare whether your local `foo_branch` is up to date with the *current* remote, you likely want:

```
# remote commit hash.
# will do a network request to get latest.
git ls-remote --head --exit-code origin foo_branch | cut -f 1

# local commit hash.
git rev-parse foo_branch
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `git rev-parse`, you should fetch the latest changes first before running `rev-parse`:

```
git fetch origin foo_branch
git rev-parse origin/foo_branch
```

I like the `git ls-remote` approach because it leaves your local repository untouched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rev-list`. Simply call `git rev-list feature_branch...origin/feature_branch` (symmetric difference). If there is no output, both commits are the same.

The cleanest way is obviously by the way of `git rev-parse` and comparing the results, as pointed out by [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110581/112968)

Comment: I don't think that's quite right: `a..b` gives you every commit in `b` which isn't also in `a`.  So, if `a` is ahead of `b`, they won't be at the same point, but the output will still be empty.

Comment: That's interesting, but it works only if `feature_branch` is **behind** `origin/feature_branch`.

Comment: @MarkLongair: oh… you are totally right! I've edited my answer to use symmetric difference. It should then work for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple command like this:

```
git diff feature_branch origin/feature_branch
```

which will shows something only if branches will points to something else.

---

```
git log -1 --decorate feature_branch
```

if it show you something like this

```
commit c1e77c1....896b (origin/feature_branch, feature_branch)
```

than both branches points to this same commit.

```
commit c1e77c1....896b (feature_branch)
```

means that branches aren't synced.

---

You also can use

```
git merge-base feature_branch origin/feature_branch
```

which will point last common commit. And next

```
git merge-base feature_branch origin/feature_branch | git show --decorate
```

---

As Mark Longair said, `git status` can be also a solution (sometime the most convenient), however this depends on your working repository, and speed of `git status` (what can be speed up by `git gc` used once a while)

Comment: Git diff will also show no difference if the commits are different but point to the same tree, so this might not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you do `git log feature_branch` it shows you history. Just check if the commit SHA id is the same as on the `git log origin/feature_branch` history.

Answer (score 0):

Simple git status should show how many commits your current branch is ahead/behind the remote. Make sure all the remotes are configured properly.