# Why do conditionals in autoconf scripts prefix variables with "x"?

Tags: autoconf

Why do conditional statements in autoconf scripts prefix their variables with "x"?  For example, the macro provided by GNU to test for Boost has conditionals such as

```
if test "x$want_boost" = "xyes"; then
```

Why is this not defined as:

```
if test "$want_boost" = "yes"; then
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some early shells, testing for an empty string variable wasn't as easy as it is now, so the best alternative was to see if "x$variable" was equal to just "x". Also, since that's apparently using `test`, that's simpler than trying to properly quote/escape sequences like '$x != "y"' without losing sanity and/or portability.

Comment: To clarify: "wasn't as easy as it is now" means that many shells were buggy and would not properly evaluate commands with an empty string like `test "" = "foo"`

Comment: The *other* reason this is necessary is that if `$variable` expands to something that begins with a dash, `test` might interpret that as an option rather than a string to be compared.  In modern shells, the equals sign takes precedence, but it was not always so.

Comment: @zwol your comment should be the answer, please make it one.

Comment: @MarcH Eh, sure, why not.

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX-compliant shells,

```
test "$foo" = "$bar"
```

does a string comparison no matter what the contents of the variables `foo` and `bar` are.  But in old, noncompliant shells, if `foo` contained something that begins with a dash, `test` would try to interpret that as a unary operator, so it would either throw a syntax error or do the wrong test.  Writing `x"$foo" = x"$bar"` makes that impossible.  I also vaguely recall problems if either argument expanded to the empty string, but that might have only been if you left out the double quotes (in which case it would be a problem with a modern shell, too).

This is particularly relevant when writing configure scripts, because, at least in principle, they're supposed to work no matter how old the shell environment is; and if you're writing a new program today, in 2020, the most plausible reason why you'd use C and autoconf is that you need portability to some old systems...